# Correctly use Eloquent relationships

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I am developing a Laravel 4 application with 4 database tables:

- Therapist
- TherapistType
- Municipality
- County

I'm using foreign keys to reference the data from other tables.
The relationships are the following:

- A therapist can have one therapist type, municipality and county
- A therapist type and municipality can belong to many therapists.
- A municipality can have one county.
- A county can belong to many municipalities and therapists.

I'm using Eloquent ORM.

This is the code I tried to use:

Therapist model:

```
public function therapistType() {
        return $this->belongsTo('TherapistType');
    }

    public function municipality() {
        return $this->hasOne('Municipality');
    }

    public function county() {
        return $this->hasOne('County');
    }
}
```

Municipality model:

```
public function county() {
        return $this->hasOne('County');
    }
```

In my controller I use the following code to fetch the therapists:

```
$therapists = Therapist::paginate(10);
return View::make('index', compact('therapists'));
```

And finally in my view this is how I'd like to get the corresponding therapist type for a therapist:

```
<span class="therapisttype">{{{ $therapist->therapistType  }}}</span>
```

However I get no data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the foreign key column referencing `TherapistType` called? It should be `therapist_type_id`. If not you need to pass the name as a second argument to `belongsTo()`

Comment: I didn't know this, thanks! But now I've got another problem. I have three therapist types, and it only returns data for the first three therapists. Also it disregards which therapist type foreign key is assigned to a therapist (it should be  the first therapist type for all therapists) and lists them all.

Comment: Try to do what @Victor suggests and echo an actual property of `TherapistType`. `{{ $therapist->therapistType->name }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$therapist->therapistType` should be returning an object, but you are not echoing the property of said object. Let us just imagine that the `therapistType` table has a `name` property, then you should do

`{{$therapist->therapistType->name}}` if you want to echo that name.

I would begin by var_dumping the object, you can use `$therapist->therapistType` assuming that you have the relationships set up correctly, you should be able to see all it's properties.

Hope it helps.